# onMouseDown on row prevents onClick or onDoubleClick event on cell from triggering react table

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, dom, react-table

I am trying to attach `handleRowMouseDown` to the mouseDown event on a **row** and another event handler to `onDoubleClick` on a **cell**

I have a tanstack table where my rows are rendered like this:

```js
const RenderRow = React.useCallback(
    ({ index, style }: { index: number; style: any }) => {
      const row = rows[index];
      prepareRow(row);
      const isRowSelected = selectedRows.includes(index);
      return (
        <div
          {...row.getRowProps({
            style,
          })}
          key={index}
          className={classNames('tr', {
            'bg-white dark:bg-zinc-950': !isRowSelected,
            'bg-blue-600 text-white': isRowSelected,
          })}
          onMouseDown={(event) => handleRowMouseDown(event, index)}
          onMouseUp={(event) => handleRowMouseUp(event, index)}
          onMouseEnter={(event) => handleRowMouseEnter(event, index)}
        >
          {row.cells.map((cell) => {
            let cellClass = classNames('td border-b border-r px-2 py-1 line-clamp-1 truncate dark:text-white ', {
              'border-gray-200 dark:border-zinc-800': !isRowSelected,
              'border-blue-700': isRowSelected,
            });

            return (
              <div {...cell.getCellProps()} className={cellClass} onDoubleClick={() => console.log('cliiiick')}>
                {cell.render('Cell')}
              </div>
            );
          })}
        </div>
      );
    },
    [prepareRow, rows, selectedRows],
  );
```

and `handleRowMouseDown` looks like this:

```js
  const handleRowMouseDown = (event: React.MouseEvent<HTMLDivElement>, rowIndex: number) => {
    if (event.shiftKey && selectedRows.length > 0) {
      const firstSelectedRow = selectedRows[0];
      const lastSelectedRow = selectedRows[selectedRows.length - 1];
      const start = Math.min(firstSelectedRow, rowIndex);
      const end = Math.max(lastSelectedRow, rowIndex);
      const newSelectedRows = Array.from({ length: end - start + 1 }, (_, i) => start + i);
      setSelectedRows(newSelectedRows);
    } else {
      setIsDragging(true);
      setDragStartIndex(rowIndex);
      if (selectedRows.length === 1 && selectedRows[0] === rowIndex) {
        setSelectedRows([]);
      } else {
        setSelectedRows([rowIndex]);
      }
    }
  };
```

onMouseDown appears to be preventing onDoubleClick (and onClick) from firing on the cell. How can I have both handlers active?

Thanks in advance :)